# Using onUnauthorized() in a Controller action derived from AuthenticatedBuilder

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

I am building a security trait using `AuthenticatedBuilder`:

```
trait Security { self: Controller =>
    object AuthenticatedAction extends AuthenticatedBuilder
        (request => getUserFromRequest(request))
}
```

I have an implementation in that trait for this function:

```
def getUserFromRequest(request: RequestHeader) = {
     // ...whatever...
}
```

This function looks for an authentication token in the request, validates it and maps it to a user id, which is then used to find a user in the database. If all is well, a `User` instance is returned, otherwise None. It's part of a wider authentication scheme, based pretty much on the play-angular-seed github project. Duplicating all of that code here is redundant, suffice to say this method either returns a `User` or `None` to signify authentication.

This lets me write a controller like this:

```
object Accounts extends Controller with Security {
    def list = AuthenticatedAction { implicit request =>
        // I can use request.user here to implement authorisation as needed
        Ok(toJson(Account.list))
    }
}
```

In this `Controller`, because of `AuthenticatedAction` I am guaranteed to have a `User` instance available via the request.user value. If there is no authorized user, the code block itself does not get executed and returns a `Forbidden` result.

This is all fine and works really well.

I have one use-case where I need to do all this authentication, but do some custom handling of the unauthorised case - i.e. I want to execute my own code block in *this* Controller when authorisation fails.

I know that `AuthenticatedBuilder` can accept such a function during construction:

```
def apply[U](userinfo: (RequestHeader) ⇒ Option[U], 
    onUnauthorized: (RequestHeader) ⇒ Result = ...): AuthenticatedBuilder[U]
```

I'm new to Scala, and I can't figure out the syntax/changes required to pass such a function from my `Controller` via my `AuthenticatedAction` object to the `AuthenticatedBuilder`. Ideally I would pass an optional `onUnauthorized` parameter, or I could have a separate `AuthenticatedAction` implementation I suppose.

How can it be done?

Comment: Editing in all those backticks really improves readability, huh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects cannot have parameter lists, so you need to use a method and create the action on the fly.

```
def Authenticated(unauth: RequestHeader => Result) =
  new AuthenticatedBuilder(getUserFromRequest, unauth)
```